# Untangling dependency cycles in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, ide, osgi, circular-dependency

I'm trying to export a plug-in feature as webstart in eclipse. After setting up feature.xml, and running the export wizard, when I click finish I get the following error:

```
A cycle was detected when generating the classpath org.pathvisio.core_2.0.11, org.pathvisio.batik.codec_1.7.0, org.pathvisio.batik.transcoder_1.7.0, org.pathvisio.pdftranscoder_1.7.0, pvplugins-bridgedbSettings_1.0.0.201106291012, org.pathvisio.core_2.0.11.
```

The trouble is, I have no idea where this cycle is exactly. So my question is: how do I find out which plug-in is causing the cyclic dependency? Are there any tools to help analyse dependency problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message above lists the exact plug-ins that makes up the elements of the cycle. It is not a single plug-in that is responsible for the cycle; it is the listed set of plug-ins... So org.pathvisio.core has a dependency on org.pathvisio.batik.codec which has a dependency on...

When you try to understand the dependencies, remember to include the installed fragments in the calculations :-)

To visualize the dependencies, I usually open the PDE editor of one of the plug-ins, go to the "Dependencies" page, in the botton-right section you have a number of tools that can help you - in this case primary "Look for cycles in the dependency graph".

Comment: Are you talking about the plugin dependencies view, or about the Dependencies tab on the page that you get when clicking MANIFEST.MF? Although I now see the dependencies tree, which is helpful, I don't see the option to "look for cycles in dependency graph" anywhere.

Comment: I am talking about the later: the dependency tab, not the view. There are - or should be - a section in the botton-right corner of the tab with the title "Dependency Analysis". Expand this, and one of the items in the section is "Look...".

Answer (score 0):

`A cycle was detected when generating the classpath`

It means that somewhere you have a plugin A requiring plugin B and plugin B requiring plugin C. plugin C requiring plugin A.

Find and fix this!

Comment: how we can find this..?